# Voice recording on Voip Calls

Tags: objective-c, call, record, voip

I am making an app that Record the call. I used AVRecorder for that but my problem is that when i record normally it record voice but when i tried to record voice when call is going on it doesn't record call. Not showing any data in Caf File.

This is my Code for Recording and stop Recording.

/* This method use to start recording This Method Can call Any where You Want to Start recording by using
  [self startRecording];  */

```
- (void) startRecording{


AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *err = nil;
[audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
if(err){
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %ld %@", [err domain], (long)[err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    return;
}
[audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
err = nil;
if(err){
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %ld %@", [err domain], (long)[err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    return;
}

recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];



[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];



// Create a new dated file
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];


 NSDate *now = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
 // NSData *finaldate =[NSData dataWithData:now];

NSString *caldate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
recorderFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.caf", Temp_Folder, caldate] ;
recoName = caldate;

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recorderFilePath];
err = nil;
recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:&err];
if(!recorder){
    NSLog(@"recorder: %@ %ld %@", [err domain], (long)[err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    UIAlertView *alert =
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                               message: [err localizedDescription]
                              delegate: nil
                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    return;
}

/* prepare to record Conversation */

[recorder setDelegate:self];
[recorder prepareToRecord];
recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;

BOOL audioHWAvailable = audioSession.inputIsAvailable;
if (! audioHWAvailable) {
    UIAlertView *cantRecordAlert =
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                               message: @"Audio input hardware not available"
                              delegate: nil
                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [cantRecordAlert show];
    //[cantRecordAlert release];
    return;
}

// start recording
[recorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval) 1000000];

}
```

/* TO Stop Recording Audio */

```
- (void) stopRecording{

[recorder stop];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: recorderFilePath];
NSError *err = nil;
NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[url path] options: 0 error:&err];

NSLog(@"Audio Data :::: %@",audioData);
if(!audioData)
    NSLog(@"audio data: %@ %ld %@", [err domain], (long)[err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
[editedObject setValue:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] forKey:@"vivek"];

}
```

Comment: Have you considered that the microphone may not be available when a call is in progress? If you're writing the VoIP app, then you should have direct access to the audio stream. If not, you're surely not going to be able to record audio from a different app.

Comment: is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Doubt it, at least not without jailbreaking the device. Being able to record some other app's audio stream would be a huge security hole -- what would stop some game or other innocuous-looking app from recording your phone calls? Furthermore, depending on jurisdiction, recording a phone call without both parties' knowledge and consent may not be legal.